# Swift accept collection in func

Tags: swift

I've made a custom class implement Collection, which works great! I basically just forward my internal array class and get map/filter/etc for free, but now I have a method which goes as follows:

```
init(items: [T])
{
    self.items = items
}
```

How can I pass my custom object to this? What should the signature be? I understand that my class isn't an array.

Comment: Is that the init method of another class? Is `self.items` necessarily an array or do you want to change that? Can you change the init method? – The simplest solution is to pass `Array(yourCustomCollection)` to the existing init method.

Comment: init is from another class yes. Didn't know about the Array trick, that would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to pass `Array(yourCustomCollection)` to the
existing `init(items: [T])`.

Alternatively, define an init method which takes a collection of `T` elements:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    var items: [T] = []

    init<C: Collection>(items: C) where C.Element == T {
        self.items = Array(items)
    }
}
```

or slightly more general, a *sequence* of `T` elements:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    var items: [T] = []

    init<S: Sequence>(items: S) where S.Element == T {
        self.items = Array(items)
    }
}
```

Or, if you want `items` to be a collection, not an array:

```
class MyClass<C: Collection> {
    var items: C

    init(items: C) {
        self.items = items
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Can we make items also more generic I just want it to be a Collection where I can loop over etc? So I can avoid the Array initializer?

Answer (score 0):

If your `items` implements `Collection`, then you can have the `init` take a `Collection`:

```
init(items: Collection) {
  self.items = items
}
```

Comment: You cannot do that. Protocol 'Collection' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements